# Need to align bootstrap element side by side

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align two input elements,a button and a progress bar, in a single row(New to CSS and bootstrap).The button doesnot line up properly with input elements.The Progress bar doesnt even show up.
The html that I'm using is as follows.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="from">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="to">
   <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-default" value="Route">
   <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class `form-inline` to the top-level div (or the parent `<form>`):

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="from">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="to">
   <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-default" value="Route">
   <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
</div>
```

Here’s the [relevant documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)

Comment: Thanks keithjgrant !. The solution is working for the two input elements and the button.But the progress bar still doesnot show up.Any idea?

Comment: @Heisenberg you're missing some of the [required markup](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-basic) for a progress bar. There are **two** DIVs that make up a progress bar.

Comment: Thanks @hungerstar.